# Из списка объектов выбрать только одно поле?

Tags: c#, рефлексия

У меня есть список объектов `Human`, у данных объектов есть поля `Name` и `Age`.

Я получаю список всех полей у объекта Human и по каждому полю я должен получить все значения из списка Humans. Как это возможно сделать? Пытался что-то сделать по примерам из гугла, но пока безрезультатно.

```
List<Human> Humans = getAllHumans();
var properties = typeof(Human).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

foreach (var property in properties)
{
    string NameField = property.Name;
    // Здесь надо получить список значений по каждому NameField из списка Humans.
}
```

Comment: Для начала `у данных объектов есть поля` и `GetProperties(...)` - это две разные вещи, ибо поля это `public int Age;`, а свойства (Property) это `public int Age {get; set;}`, надеюсь это опечатка у вас. Ну а получение `var value = property.GetValue(Humans[0]);`, естественно `Humans[0]` надо заменить циклом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Будет что-то типа такого. Для полей просто изменить на `GetFields`

```
List<Human> humans = getAllHumans()

foreach(var human in humans)
{
   var properties = typeof(Human)
         .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
         .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, object>(x.Name, x.GetValue(human)))
}
```

Comment: Рефлексию частично можно из цикла вынести и матеоиплизовать в массив. У автора правильно было.